# Regex Email validation with some special cases

Tags: regex, ruby

I know there is a lot of question like that here, but I really cannot make it works, so any help here would be great!

I have such Regex: `FORMAT = /\A([^@\s^,]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i` (Ruby)

And I have this set of data:

```
VALID_VALUES = [
          "a@test.com",
          "user@test.com",
          "user@exa-test.net",
          "first.last+1@example.COM",
          "fir5t_la5t@examp.le",
          "FIRST+LAST@e.xamp.le",
          "#{'a' * 242}@example.com",
          "first-last@example.com"
        ].freeze

        INVALID_VALUES = [
          "double.dot@example..org",
          "no_at_sign.net",
          "double@at@sign.com",
          "without@dot,com",
          "ends+with@dot.",
          "test,user@test.se",
          "first.last.@example.com"
        ].freeze
```

The only case that is missing is for `first.last.@example.com`, which is reported as a valid one, but should be invalid.

Any help here would be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"#{'a' * 243}@example.com",` also shows as valid.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am handling it just check the length too, outside of regex. I will remove it from the data set.

Comment: Ok, then all you need is `/\A([^@\s^,]+)\b@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i` or `/\A([^@\s^,]+)(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i`. The answer depends on what characters are allowed right before `@`, just alphanumerics or alphanumerics and `_`. The `[^@\s^,]` is too broad. Do you know `[^@\s^,]` matches any char but `@`, whitespace, `^` and comma?

Comment: Great, yes, maybe I miss something about the `[^@\s^,]`. But it works great now.  Thx!